# Type Issue in appendChild

Tags: javascript

I get the following error:

```
Type Issue
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'commands.appendChild')
```

On the following line:

```
commands.appendChild(inputConfirm);
```

`commands` comes from

```
var commands = document.forms['commands'];
```

There's no error here, so I believe `commands` is a valid form object. `inputConfirm` comes from

```
var inputConfirm = document.createElement('input');
```

No error here either, so it should be valid as well. I also set some attributes of `inputConfirm` with no error.

What could be the cause? I'm clueless...

**Edit:** the script was being executed in a `document.onload` event. See the confirmed answer below

Comment: " so I believe commands is a valid form object" - `console.log` it, see what it returns. Alternatively, maybe you have a scope issue where you defined commands in a different scope? Could you provide a minimal but complete code sample that illustrates the issue?

Comment: `document.forms['key']` doesn't throw an error if you use a key that doesn't exists, it just returns `undefined`, which is what you have, so there's your problem right there.

Comment: In `document.forms['key']`, should `'key'` be the id of a form, or it's name?

Comment: @Dunno it's actually the index, if you want to select a form by ID you can use `document.getElementById`

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: As Benjamin said, you should use `document.getElementsById('commands');` assuming commands is the id

Comment: Ugh how annoying, I can't make a jsfiddle that would reproduce the problem! And `getElemetById` returns `null`. I'll see if I can work out what's not working without posting the full code (it's big and ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.forms` is an array that contains the forms of the page. Array indexes must be positive numbers, so `document.forms[0]` is valid, `document.forms['commands']` is not. It references an undefined index, so the result is, logically, `undefined`. Use `document.getElementById()`, assumind 'commands' is the id:

```
var form = document.getElementById('commands');
form.appendChild(...);
```

**EDITED**

Make sure that the element exists when you execute this code (I mean, the DOM is ready). If you have this code in a `<script>` tag or external file in the `<head>` and you haven't wrapped it in a `window.onload` or `document.DOMContentLoaded` event you'll find that `document.getElementById` returns `null`.

To avoid this, as said, put the code in an event handler for any of those events, or just beore the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: It returns me a `null`. What the hell is happening D:

Comment: your form doesn't have an `id` attribute set to  *'commands'*. Make sure that this is in the code: `<form id="commands" ...>`.

Comment: Of course it is, I wouldn't make *that* kind of mistake. And it works in the console... Ugh, maybe it's something on the server side? Sorry about making a mess here

Comment: Are you calling `document.getElementById` before the page has finished loading? Where is this code?

Comment: Haha, yes, that's it! I used `document.onload` instead of `window.onload` and it messed things up